# Left join and Inner join in same mysql query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have three tables and trying to use left join and inner join in same query with the three tables. But its not working the way i want.
i have four tags A,B,C,D and only two tags are used by agent_id=22.
Below is the query i am using

```
SELECT MDT.tags,COUNT(MDTM.tag_id) AS tagCount
    FROM mp_desk_agent_added_customers MDAC
    INNER JOIN mp_desk_tags_match MDTM 
    ON MDAC.u_cust_id=MDTM.u_cust_id
    INNER JOIN mp_desk_tags MDT
    ON MDTM.tag_id=MDT.tag_id
    WHERE MDAC.agent_id=22
    GROUP BY MDT.tag_id
```

The result i am getting is just two tag name and their count which is present in tag_match table. But i want all the four tag name and count as 0 for the tags which are not present in tag_match table.

### TABLES STRUCTURE

**mp_desk_tags**

tag, tag_id

**mp_desk_tags_match**

tag_match_id,tag_id,u_cust_id

**mp_desk_agent_added_customers**

u_cust_id,agent_id

Comment: any chance you can post the structure of the data? It seems to me that both joins should be left joins, but it depends on your data structure and values.

Comment: yeah.. i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four tags and you want four result records, one per tag. So select from the tags table. You get the count with a sub-select.

```
select
  tag_id, 
  tag,
  (
    select count(*)
    from mp_desk_tags_match dtm
    where dtm.tag_id = dt.tag_id
    and u_cust_id in
    (
      select u_cust_id
      from mp_desk_agent_added_customers
      where agent_id = 22
    )
  ) as tag_count
from mp_desk_tags dt;
```

Here is the same with joins:

```
select
  dt.tag_id, 
  dt.tag,
  count(*)
from mp_desk_tags dt
left join mp_desk_tags_match dtm on dtm.tag_id = dt.tag_id
left join mp_desk_agent_added_customers daac on daac.u_cust_id = dtm.u_cust_id 
                                                and daac.agent_id = 22
group by dt.tag_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MDT.tag_id,COUNT(MDTM.tag_id) AS tagCount
FROM mp_desk_agent_added_customers MDAC
INNER JOIN mp_desk_tags_match MDTM 
ON MDAC.u_cust_id=MDTM.u_cust_id
AND MDAC.agent_id=22
RIGHT JOIN mp_desk_tags MDT
ON MDTM.tag_id=MDT.tag_id
GROUP BY MDT.tag_id
```

Comment: no its returning the same result  with tag_id 1 and 2 and their count. But not 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your table structure your query should be:

```
SELECT MDT.tags,COUNT(MDTM.tag_id) AS tagCount
    FROM mp_desk_agent_added_customers MDAC
    INNER JOIN mp_desk_tags_match MDTM 
    ON MDAC.u_cust_id=MDTM.u_cust_id
    LEFT JOIN mp_desk_tags MDT
    ON MDTM.tag_id=MDT.tag_id
    WHERE MDAC.agent_id=22
    GROUP BY MDT.tag_id
```

This is assuming that the first tabel MDAC does not have a record being returned in the MDT table which would case your totals to only display for the first 2 tag id's